# Who introduced nerves in category theory?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, soft-question, ho.history-overview

Who was the first to consider that categories were semi-simplicial sets (and in particular groupoids were simplicial sets)?

I think there was a concept of nerve of a covering in algebraic topology before (maybe Alexandroff).

Comment: This would be better on http://hsm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Eilenberg-Zilber?

Comment: Maybe G. Segal did but attributes it too Grothendieck

Comment: In the context of algebraic topology, nerves play a fundamental role in the definition of Čech cohomology. The nLab asserts (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%C4%8Cech+nerve) that this is how Čech gave his definition, presumably in the 1930s.

Comment: I think this paper is usually cited http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1968__34__105_0.pdf

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Segal and Grothendieck did not introduce nerves: they introduced the idea of characterizing which simplicial sets are isomorphic to nerves. It is definitely Čech who introduced nerves of coverings.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski  the question is asking who introduced nerves of categories not nerves of coverings which undoubtedly goes back to cech.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg My comment on Segal and Grothendieck stands: they did not introduce nerves.

Comment: I do not know which paper introduced nerves first, but I think the first textbook is Gabriel and Zisman's Calculus of Fractions and Homotopy Theory, Springer, 1967 (they discuss nerves in full generality for sure).

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski Segal doesn't claim originality.  I don't know the history well enough. Gabriel and Zisman is a similar time period I have no idea which was drafted first or what Gothendieck explicitly did.  But many papers do claim Segal's paper as an original reference

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski: Nerves of covers were introduced by Paul Alexandroff in his 1928 paper Über den allgemeinen Dimensionsbegriff und seine Beziehungen zur elementaren geometrischen Anschauung.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks!

Comment: DOI link for Alexandroff's article: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01451612, (and free pdf link: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/alexdim.pdf). I wonder if he talked with Noether about this stuff...

Comment: I'd remark that we have a highly related (though not exactly the same) question on the nerve construction's use in algebraic topology here in case it's of interest: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98824/origins-of-the-nerve-theorem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Peter Johnstone's 1977 "Topos theory" (p.48) the simplicial description of categories is attributed to Grothendieck and he cites the "Technique de la descente"-series of Bourbaki seminars 1959-62 for it. I guess what he has in mind is in particular prop.4.1 on page 108 of the third installment [Préschémas quotients](http://archive.numdam.org/article/SB_1960-1961__6__99_0.pdf) from 1961.

Comment: This seems to be supported by Grothendieck himself.

In a note of ["Pursuing stacks"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.01000.pdf) section 16bis pg 52, he says

Comment: The definition of the nerve functor,
realizing a full embedding of (Cat) into \Simplexˆ,
is given for the first time (I believe) in a
Bourbaki talk of mine, which at that time
wasn’t concerned at all with the topological
interpretation of small categories, but with
some rather formal prerequisites for the
operation of “passage to quotient” of an
object by a “pre-equivalence relation”, in
any category (with a view of applying it in
the category of schemes. . . )